# Runtime error при решении задачи

Tags: java

Решаю задачи на сайте, при отправке сервер выдает Runtime error. Как её исправить?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader inf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String n = inf.readLine();
        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(n);
        int arr[] = new int[1002];
        int crop = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            String m = inf.readLine();
            Integer count = Integer.parseInt(m);
            arr[i] = count;         
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < (num - 2); j++) {
            if (crop < arr[j] + arr[j + 1] + arr[j + 2]) {
                crop = arr[j] + arr[j + 1] + arr[j + 2];
            }
        }

       if (num>2) {    
         if (crop < arr[num-2]+arr[num-1]+arr[0]){
           crop = arr[num-2]+arr[num-1]+arr[0];
         }
         else  if (crop < arr[num-1]+arr[0]+arr[1]){
                 crop = arr[num-1]+arr[0]+arr[1];
         }
       }

        System.out.print(crop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Под ограничение на num ваш код подходит? Например, при num=1 ошибка очевидна, обращение к отрицательному элементу массива в строке `if (crop < arr[num-2]+arr[num-1]+arr[0])`

Comment: Для этого нужно знать что за ошибка происходит, в какой строке и, желательно, на каких входных данных. А то так можно долго и упорно гадать на кофейной гуще. С `num`, кстати, кроме проблем со значениями `<=1` есть ещё проблемы и со значениями `>=1003`. Зачем создавать массив с длиной, заданной магической константой `1002`, если количество элементов задаётся переменной `num` чуть выше, и его вполне можно использовать для установки длины массива?

Comment: @iksuy даже если ограничение есть, не проходит

Comment: @Regent у меня компилируется, тесты проходят, а вот на сервере нет...

Comment: @ТинаПогодина то есть узнать на какой строке какой именно `Exception` при каких данных происходит вы не можете? Насчет тестов: так, может, вы не все варианты рассматриваете? И не экономьте, пожалуйста, на пробелах в коде.

Comment: @Regent нет, не могу сказать в какой строке. я так понимаю, что у меня именно ошибка в исполнении. на другом  языке такой же код прошел

Comment: Однако же код компилируется и работает. Может, я не знаю, должно быть (для правильной обработки сервером результата) `System.out.println`, а не `System.out.print`?

Comment: @Regent все равно нет

Comment: @ТинаПогодина, Javarush?

Comment: Тогда не знаю. Я бы несколько укоротил код за счет использования `Scanner` вместо `BufferedReader` и убрал бы дублирование кода при вычислении `crop`, но на результат это никак не повлияет.

Comment: @Sv__t    нет, на   acmp

Comment: @ТинаПогодина думаю, будет нелишним, если вы опубликуете исчерпывающее условие задачи и те ограничения, которые условие задачи объявляет. Любые мелочи могут иметь значение, так как автоматические тесты заточены на их проверки.

Comment: @Regent        во всех источниках советую не использовать Scanner, поэтому BufferedReader

Comment: @ТинаПогодина, метод readLine генерирует IOException, оберните его в try/catch, а также обработайте ситуации когда передается строка, а не число иначе это вызовет в рантайме NumberFormatException

Comment: @Regent, в задачах по спортивному программированию `Scanner` не стоит использовать, потому как он очень медленный, в задачах, где много данных на ввод-вывод бывают случаи, когда решение не укладывается в time limit именно из-за использования `Scanner`.

Comment: @iksuy если считываются тысячи чисел, то да, согласен, смысл в использовании `BufferedReader` определённо есть. Я, не занимаясь подобными задачами, как-то и не привык видеть в `System.in` больше десятка чисел за раз.